# How do I configure split tunneling with Open VPN

Tags: openvpn, split-tunnel

I have Open VPN running on an AWS Linux 2 server with and running the client app on Android.

How do I set up split tunneling?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Openvpn split tunnel](https://openvpn.net/solutions/use-cases/split-tunneling-with-access-server/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Admin%20Web%20UI,networks%20will%20traverse%20the%20VPN.)

How do I set it up in OpenVPN Access Server?

> In the Admin Web UI, you can start split tunneling with a simple click
> of a toggle button. Under Configuration > VPN Settings > Routing,
> switch “Should client Internet traffic be routed through the VPN?” to
> No. Once set to ‘no’, traffic destined to your private networks will
> traverse the VPN. Other traffic will bypass the VPN.
>
> In addition to this setting, you also need to define the private
> subnets clients need access. You can do this under Configuration > VPN
> Settings > Routing by specifying the subnets in the input field with
> the label: “Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be
> given access (one per line)”

Comment: What is the URL for the admin web UI?

Comment: Try this article for AWS: ....  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/split-tunnel-vpn.html

Comment: This will also be useful.    https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/awsmarketplace/setting-up-openvpn-access-server-in-amazon-vpc/